Exo player animation is canceled
I want to animate the visibility of the exo player after clicking on the button, but the player suddenly disappears or appears suddenly.
@Composable
fun TestPlayerScreen(
    modifier: Modifier = Modifier,
) {
    val context = LocalContext.current
    val exoPlayer =
        ExoPlayer.Builder(context)
            .build()

    val mediaSource = remember {
        MediaItem.Builder()
            .setUri("http://commondatastorage.googleapis.com/gtv-videos-bucket/sample/BigBuckBunny.mp4")
            .build()
    }
    val playerView = remember {
        PlayerView(context).apply {
            player = exoPlayer
        }
    }
    var showPlayer by remember {
        mutableStateOf(true)
    }
    DisposableEffect(mediaSource) {
        exoPlayer.setMediaItem(mediaSource)
        exoPlayer.prepare()
        onDispose {
            exoPlayer.release()
        }
    }
    Column {
        AnimatedVisibility(
            visible = showPlayer, modifier
                .width(300.dp)
                .height(200.dp),
            enter = fadeIn(tween(5000)) ,
            exit = fadeOut(tween(5000))
        ) {
            AndroidView(
                factory = {
                    playerView
                }
            )
        }
        Button(onClick = { showPlayer = !showPlayer }) {
            Text("Show/Hide player")
        }
    }
}

tried to animate alpha as a state, but the result is the same
